# Create bouncycastle PGPSecretKey with an email

Tags: java, bouncycastle, encryption-asymmetric

I need to create a public key for a unix machine to send me encrypted data.

What I do is use the following constructor for creating the PGPSecreyKey.

```
PGPSecretKey secretKey = new PGPSecretKey(PGPSignature.DEFAULT_CERTIFICATION, PGPPublicKey.RSA_GENERAL, publicKey, privateKey, new Date(),
            "Test test@mail.com", PGPEncryptedData.CAST5, passPhrase, null, null, new SecureRandom(), "BC");
```

When opened with Kleopatra (to check my certificate) I see Name: "Test test@mail.com" and Email: "".

How can I create a PGP key with both a name and email (and comment if possible).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to add an emailaddress you have to concat the email to the userID.
LIke

```
PGPPublicKey.RSA_GENERAL, publicKey, privateKey, new Date(),
            "Hans Mueller <hans.mueller@mail.com>", PGPEncryptedData.CAST5, passPhrase, null, null, new SecureRandom(), "BC");
```

Answer (score -2):

to Fix this issue you have to add \n newline between name and Email

```
PGPPublicKey.RSA_GENERAL, publicKey, privateKey, new Date(),
            "Hans Mueller \n <hans.mueller@mail.com>", PGPEncryptedData.CAST5, passPhrase, null, null, new SecureRandom(), "BC");
```